# Is consensual sex between adult siblings (and pornographic material thereof) legal?

Tags: european-union, pornography, sexual-offences

I was reading an article about a scandal involving a politician (allegedly) trying to set up a meeting with a porn actress, and it mentioned that the actress is mainly known for having a twin sister who is also a porn actress, and for performing with her.

This made me wonder whether consensual sex between adult siblings is legal, and whether pornography made of such activity is legal. Because the incest taboo is historically based on genetic defects in the offspring resulting from incestuous sex, I also wonder whether the siblings being male and/or female makes any difference.

Jurisdiction: the people mentioned in the article are EU citizens, but I'd also be interested in answers about other jurisdictions where extra-marital sex, homosexuality and pornography are legal in general.

Comment: the laws generally don't care for homosexual relations of that type but mostly for heterosexual ones.

Comment: @Trish [It varies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_incest#Laws_regarding_consensual_incest)  Legal for same-sex couples, Illegal for opposite-sex couples is not very common with only 2 EU countries having that law.

Comment: @User65535 **interesting**! I seem to have stretched my knowledge on Germany too all of Europe there...

Comment: @User65535 That map is very different from what I had expected. Ironically, the actresses live in a country where it is illegal "if it provokes public scandal" :-)

Comment: Obviously a porn actress who "works with her twin sister" isn't necessarily telling the truth. Might be just an unrelated other actress who looks similar.

Answer (score 3):

### This is incest

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

[Incest](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s61h.html) is defined as sexual intercourse between close family members which includes siblings and half-siblings. [Sexual intercourse](http://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s61ha.html) includes penetration of the genitalia or anus with any part of the body or any manipulated object and application of the mouth or tongue to female genitalia (among other acts). It earns you up to 8 years imprisonment.

There is no specific law against pornography depicting implied or illegal acts (child pornography excepted). However, I suspect such material would be Refused Classification; the distribution of which is a crime attracting a penalty of up to 12 months.

Comment: What country's jurisdiction are you talking about ?

Comment: @Gouvernathor no country - the state of New South Wales as it says in the answer

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Incest is legal in France, Spain, Portugal, The Netherlands, Luxembourg and Belgium. In [Sweden](https://www.government.se/4a4563/contentassets/7a2dcae0787e465e9a2431554b5eab03/the-swedish-criminal-code.pdf), under Ch. 6 §7-8 vaginal intercourse with one's own child or its descendant, or with a full sibling, is guilty of the respective crimes sexual intercourse with a descendant or sibling. In Italy under [Article 564 of the Penal code](https://www.altalex.com/documents/news/2014/11/10/dei-delitti-contro-la-famiglia), a similar descendant / sibling law (without the vaginal restriction) is in force, but only in case a public scandal arises. I'd say, you have to pick a specific country to get the specifics, if I didn't list a country of interest.

Comment: FWIW, the pornographic material itself of the act isn't necessarily illegal although its production might involve conspiracy to commit the crime of incest.

Comment: Leaving aside child porn, AFAIK pornography is legal throughout the EU, though Malta may be an edge case.